# Zeppelin started in k8s mode, spark engine reported an error

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Zeppelin starts in k8s mode, and the master of the spark engine is k8s:// https://kubernetes.default.svc Starting the Spark Basic Features of the example, a java. io. IOException: Launching zeppelin interpreter on kubernetes is time out, kill it now was reported. How can I solve this problem

I hope he can run normally